# Selenium IDE : How to use pattern checking for a dynamic id using XPath

Tags: selenium, pattern-matching, selenium-ide

In my website there is a recently uploaded image section.
in this section all recently uploaded images are displayed randomly

using firepath i traced the xpath of that location

```
//div[@id='udtkbdf50']/a/div[2]/div
```

so on each time page refresh this  `@id='udtkbdf50'` value changes ,only one thing is common that is the value is always starting with   `u`

so i want to use pattern matching technique [regular expression or Globbing Patterns ]

`@id='udtkbdf50'`  for this value and rest of the path i.e  `/a/div[2]/div` will remain same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`//div[contains(@id,'u')]/a/div[2]/div` will work.

**UPDATE:**

`//div[starts-with(@id,'u')]/a/div[2]/div` will be more specific.

All d best.